# How to change imagebutton click event method

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, click, imagebutton

I have an imagebutton which i set up at design time via the designer and assigned a method to its Click event. I need to now change that buttons target event method dynamically.

I have tried this by setting the following code but it doesn't seem to alter the target event for the imagebutton to my desired method 'imgBtnFw_Click_Details'

```
imgBtn.Click +=new ImageClickEventHandler(imgBtnFw_Click_Details);
```

Im thinking maybe i need to detach the currently assigned click event but not sure.

Does anybody have a correct set of steps for switching the target firing event method?

Comment: Try to remove initial click handler declaration from markup, and set it programmatically. Then based on the conditions you will change the event handler dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working...

Event Binding..

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            imgBtn.Click -= ImageButton1_Click;   // remove previous handler
            imgBtn.Click +=imgBtnFw_Click_Details; // add new handler
        }
    }
```

Event handler ...

```
 protected void imgBtnFw_Click_Details(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
   //your implementation
 }
```

Comment: can you set up a asp.net c# web site, add image button, give it click event via the designer and then pending some objects value have it set the click event to a new method?

Comment: Fearghal, we change button event handler into page load event.

Comment: Can you explain or elaborate on your answer code? I see my code being hit so expected the click event to result in the new method being fired but no :(

Comment: if you can bind into handler into page load event then its working.
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ImageButton1.Click -= ImageButton1_Click;
                ImageButton1.Click += ImageButton_ClickEvent;
            }
        }

        Please try this ...

Comment: ahhh, that worked. So why does it need to be in page_load, why cant i put it in page_prerender or how can i put it in a method outside after page_load?

Comment: Thanks fearghal... you can follow this link for event handling http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/01/14/asp-net-page-life-cycle-diagram.aspx please mark this answer if its valuable for you :)